# How to add current datetimepicker and add second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

Demo and full code is like this : http://fiddle.jshell.net/TC6Gr/436/

My javascript code is like this :

```
$('#time-start').datetimepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii',
    autoclose: true,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
    maxView: 3,
    minuteStep: 1
})
```

I want the code executed, it's will view current datetime. I want to view second too. So, second also viewed. The second also selected. I had searching response in google, but I don't find it. I'm still confused

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: do you mean you want datetimepicker for second element too?

Comment: @JayeshChitroda, Yes, I want display second element too. Besides, I want to display current datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dgb09c5c/2/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 start-date">
   <div class='input-group date' id="time-end">
      <input type='text' id="time-start" class="form-control" placeholder="End Time" >
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
   var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
   return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
}



    var d = new Date,
        dformat = [ (d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(),
                    d.getDate().padLeft(),
                    d.getFullYear()].join('/')+
                    ' ' +
                  [ d.getHours().padLeft(),
                    d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
                    d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
     $('#time-start').val(dformat);

$('#time-start').datetimepicker({
     format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii:ss',
    autoclose: true,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
    maxView: 3,
    minuteStep: 1
})
```

Comment: jsfiddle is the same as mine. I did not find the answers. I want to show the full datetime. for example 2016-07-20 13:53:10. I want can select seconds

Comment: Now check this. I have updated script. Change the format. it will sure solve your problem.

Comment: I don't select second. I want can select the second too

Comment: Look here : http://jsfiddle.net/CujDK/4/. I want display like that. But I'm still confused

Comment: In your example. there are 6 external resources (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js and bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js). Download last 2 js and put it in your library. it will let you select time too.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I want ask again. How to display current datetime? So when the script executed, It will display current datetime

Comment: Update the script above the function datetimepicker(). See I have update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117911/discussion-between-gunjal-ray-and-samuel-toh).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function getDateTime() {
    var now     = new Date(); 
    var year    = now.getFullYear();
    var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
    var day     = now.getDate();
    var hour    = now.getHours();
    var minute  = now.getMinutes();
    var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
    if(month.toString().length == 1) {
        var month = '0'+month;
    }
    if(day.toString().length == 1) {
        var day = '0'+day;
    }   
    if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
        var hour = '0'+hour;
    }
    if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
        var minute = '0'+minute;
    }
    if(second.toString().length == 1) {
        var second = '0'+second;
    }   
    var dateTime = year+'/'+month+'/'+day+' '+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;   
     return dateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add second input for datetimepicker with id time-end and initialize datetimepicker for it too:

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wxoud40L/

```
<div class="col-sm-6 start-date">
   <div class='input-group date' id="time-end">
      <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="End Time" readonly>
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon lyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#time-end').datetimepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii:ss',
    timeFormat: 'hh:ii:ss',
    autoclose: true,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
    maxView: 3,
    minuteStep: 1
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle is the same as mine. I did not find the answers. I want to show the full datetime. for example 2016-07-20 13:53:10. I want can select seconds

Comment: I don't select second. I want can select the second

Comment: Look here : http://jsfiddle.net/CujDK/4/. I want display like that. But I'm still confused