# Bootstrap DateRangePicker Calendar and Right/Left Icon not Appearing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using Bootstrap Date Range Picker, and in this I am unable to get the Calendar and Left/Right Arrow glyphicon.

Below is my code that I have Implemented.

```
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Code for Date Range Picker on Page:

```
<label style="padding-right:5px;">Select range: </label>    
  <h:inputText id="dateRangeFilterArchive" class="dateRangeArchive" style="width:200px;height:35px;vertical-align:center;text-align:center"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(function() {
            $('.dateRangeArchive').daterangepicker();
            });
        });
  </script>
```

However the glyphicon for Calendar and Left/Right Arrow do not appear.

[image: Glyphicon for Calendar and Left?right Arrow not appearing]

Any Help is appreciated,

Thanks,
Mufaddal.

Comment: [Try this link:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501486/how-to-add-current-datetimepicker-and-add-second/38501747#38501747) Probably this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but did not help :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't add `daterangepicker.js` and `daterangepicker.css` in your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `daterangepicker.js`

Find this code

```
html += '<th class="prev available"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left icon icon-arrow-left glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i></th>'
```

And this

```
html += '<th class="next available"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right icon icon-arrow-right glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></th>'
```

Edit like this

```
html += '<th class="prev available"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i></th>'
.....
html += '<th class="next available"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></th>'
```

It's work for me